# Why is my AB Line in the GGPlot Package not visible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Maybe it is the most stupid question and it worked a million times for me, but my Ab line is just not visible in the graph. What am I doing wrong?

My code

```
plot =ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x= data$ï..Year, y= loggdp))+
  geom_line(col="blue")+
  geom_abline( slope=0.01994632, intercept=11.96591, col="red" )
```

And this is the graph I get

[image: And this is the graph I get]

Comment: Looks like it might be below the graph minimum y-values. Try increasing the intercept as a test and if that's the problem, you'll have to adjust the y-axis range to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because it's outside of the visible area. For `x=2000` (year 2000), the slope and intercept you have passed result (roughly) in a value of `11.96 + 2000*0.02 = 51.96` which is not in the y-axis range in this plot.